# Ejecutar un un ActionListener de un botón en java dentro de un ciclo/bucle

Tags: java, java-swing

¿Alguien sabe o me podría recomendar una forma en la cual pueda ejecutar un `ActionListener` de un botón el cual al ejecutarlo me devuelva algún valor, todo dentro de un ciclo? Esto lo digo ya que cuando trato de hacer esto mismo dentro de un método, el método imprime las veces que el ciclo se repite el valor que tiene cargado por defecto antes de dejarme cambiar este valor con el botón.

Con `JOptionPane` sí logré hacer que el ciclo se ejecute. Me salga la ventana de texto, escribo y luego el ciclo se vuelve a repetir de esa manera hasta que se cierra.

Gracias.

Comment: Si quieres que te ayudemos necesitas subir el código de lo que tienes hecho, y sobre eso podremos intentar darte una respuesta. Sin código a saber... Solo decirte que un listener es algo que registras y que se ejecuta posteriormente, cuando se pulsa el botón o se produce el evento. Así que no puedes pensar que se va a ejecutar de forma secuencial allí donde lo registras.

Comment: Verás, estoy realizando una especie de juego en la cual un servidor envía preguntas a un cliente para luego comprobar las respuestas del cliente, el código que tengo como tal es un método que conecta al servidor con el cliente e inicia un ciclo mantiene la comunicación, hasta ahí estoy bien, pero necesito que las respuestas sean enviadas hacia el servidor por medio de botones o alguna alternativa que se pueda insertar en en un `JPanel` el problema es ese, que necesito que sea ejecutado de manera secuencial. Gracias por la edición por cierto, aún soy nuevo.

Comment: Pues tendrás que cambiar la idea de tu aplicación. Desde el momento en el que incluyes interfaz gráfica y Listener para botones, pierdes la posibilidad de que tu aplicación se ejecute de forma secuencial. Y esto es porque el usuario pulsará los botones cuando le de la gana y será ahí, en respuesta a la pulsación, cuando tendrás que enviar la respuesta al servidor. Pero es todo muy genérico. Piensa en un listener como un trozo de código en el que indicas qué quieres que se ejecute cuando se llame. El código pasa por ahí, registra el listener y continua su ejecución sin detenerse.

Comment: Las instrucciones que me dieron para realizar esta aplicación eran que tenia que poseer una interfaz gráfica pero hasta ahora no estaba tan enterado de las limitaciones de este tipo de función. Tienes razón, tendré que replantearme la forma en la que realizaré la aplicación... De todas formas muchas gracias por aclararme más el comportamiento de las interfaces!

Comment: Creo que según tu problema se soluciona es implementando hilos, busca documentación sobre ello. Te aseguro que este es el camino. Saludos